# AngularJS - how to include a template without a wrapper

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example I have a template like the following.

template.html:

```
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
```

I want to include it anywhere I want without a wrapper, so the result is like this:

```
<body>
.
.
<div>div1</div>
<div>div2</div>
.
.
</body>
```

I can't use `ng-include` because it has a wrapper `<ng-include>`.

I tried creating a directive with `replace:true`, but an error says the template must have only one root element.

If it is a comment directive without `replace:true`, then the template won't show.

What should I do? I need this because a wrapper will mess up the layout.

Comment: You've already specified the possibilities and the reasons why they are not options. This isn't how directives should be used. Depending on what you're trying to do, this may be XY problem that can be solved by modifying current layout/styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
app.directive('i', ['$interpolate', function($interpolate) {
  return {
    scope: {
      i: '<'
    },
    template: '<div>{{ i.text1 || \'DIV1\' }}</div><div>{{ i.text2 || \'DIV2\' }}</div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.after($interpolate(element.html())(scope));
      element.remove();
    }
  };
}]);
```

here is plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/hRHMcvTfC2BNETO64SnW?p=preview

you can pass text variables to be printed, if not passed - devault 'DIV1' and 'DIV2' will be printed

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the layout/styles. It is recommend to not use `replace:true`, because its deprecated and angular directives must have only one root element.